# Chainloading an efi file sitting in.an ISO

Tags: grub2, uefi, boot-loader

I have an iso file on disc I want to boot. It contains an efi file in it. I can mount it as loopback, but I get an error saying 'invalid root' when I try chainloading. I've tried setting root to loop and (loop).

How do I chainload an efi file inside an iso?

Comment: Shouldn't loop the ISO instead?

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes `loop` is the loopback for iso.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possibly to chainload another efi file from within an ISO. You can only chainload other efi files available directly from efi (so not from loops or filesystems accessibly by grub2 through it's own drivers). Grub is not proxying the access to the data but only responsible for calling another thing after initialization.
The other thing can be a chain-loaded efi file which needs to be able to bootstrap as when it had been called directly by uEFI (having only the view on hardware that uEFI provides so cannot use grubs loop mounts or filesystem or crypto drivers).
The other thing can be a linux kernel (or something that is compatible to it) where grub supplies arguemnts to the kernel - and sets up an ramdisk handed over to the linux kernel as initial root device. Besides this intial ramdisk and and the arguments provided to the kernel it has also only the view on the plain uEFI system (having only the view on hardware that uEFI provides so cannot use grubs loop mounts or filesystem or crypto drivers).

The grub2 loopback driver is made for loading linux kernels where the kernels and the initial ramdisk are loaded from the loopback device by grub. There are kernel images around that could be loaded directly from efi and have an efi extension, so if You want to load such efi file it is possible to load it as a kernel (so not chainloading by grub2 but loading/booting).
What is the solution to boot Your images from image file and wheter it is possible at all depends on Yiur images contents.

Comment: How is it that syslinux memdisk can boot iso files as though they were actually physically inserted, but grub in uefi mode can not, even if the iso image has efi boot files?